# Matlab - how to use specgram function?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I loaded wav file by [data,fs,bit] = wavread('*.wav');
I want to use specgram function to visualize this wav file.

Like this!

[image]

Let me know how can I visualize wav file like this picture.
(I want to analyze the frequency of wav file's sound)

Comment: ummm... Have you tried reading Matlab `specgram` and see their examples? Hint : `spectrogram`

Comment: I tried but I couldnt find any examples. Maybe I cant read english well...

Comment: `spectrogram` can visualize a single signal, but your wav file is probably stereo. If you don't know, what does `size(data)` return?

Comment: @Daniel size(data) returns [24297 1].. is it stereo?

Comment: @Matputer that means it is single channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh...I do not give the plot example as Matlab `specgram` and `spectrogram`, but I will give another way to do it.

First you want to use FFT to transform your Time Domain signal to Short Time Frequency Domain (STFT):

This can be done by matlab `specgram`:

```
[data,fs,bit] = wavread('test.wav'); %//Read in WAV file
%//Note if you have dual channel or multi-channel, you need to do each channel separately, or add them to create mono-channel. In my example, which is voice, I use a single channel recording.
teststft = spectrogram(data); %//This is rough, and usually results in terrible results;
%//I suggest you set your input parameters suitable for voice/music/etc - Note I used hamming window of 256 length, 50% overlap and 512 nfft - which creates roughly 30ms time frames, suitable for voice.

teststft = spectrogram(data(:,1),hamming(256),50,512);

%//In your plotting example, you have used something like the Log Magnitude response, which can be expressed as:
testSTFT = log(abs(teststft));

%//and finally, to plot:

figure
surf(STFT, 'edgecolor', 'none'); view(0,90); axis tight;
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('FrequencyDistribution');
grid on;
```

Result looks like:
     [image]